# Actual line numbers for listings: firstnumber=\inputlineno is off by one

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I would like to have the actual line numbers next to my code listings but if I use `firstnumber=\inputlineno`, this gets evaluated one line too early:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left, firstnumber=\inputlineno, frame = single}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
... here is some great code on line 6 in our file ...
\end{lstlisting}
This is line $\the\inputlineno$ in our file.
\end{document}
```

[image: line number 5 shown, should be 6]

Naively, I want to do `firstnumber=\inputlineno+1`. How?

Something I already tried was `firstnumber=\value{mycounter}` and set this counter to the right value at the beginning of the code listing via `\AtBeginEnvironment` or `\lstnewenvironment`.
Both gave me the error "You can't use `\inputlineno' in horizontal mode.".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try `firstnumber=\numexpr\inputlineno+1\relax`. Just out of curiosity: why do you want to use the actual input line number? Could you perhaps expand on your example?

Comment: Thank you @Jubobs, this works beautifully! Could you post it as an answer so I can properly thank you for it? I kept the example as minimal as possible - my real .lhs file contains a lot of haskell code in literate programming style. So especially for errors coming from the Haskell compiler it is nice to have the actual input line numbers also in the PDF.

Comment: The value of `\inputlineno` corresponds to the line where `\begin{lstlisting}` is scanned.

Comment: @m4lvin No problem. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity.

Comment: @egreg Do you have a reference for that? Did you find an explanation in the `listings` source code?

Comment: @Jubobs `\inputlineno` is a primitive of TeX; it is an integer register that has the value of the line number in the file that TeX is currently reading, at the point of reading.

Comment: @egreg Ok but, when the first line number gets typeset, are we not on the input line following that containing `\begin{lstlisting}`?

Comment: @Jubobs No, because `listings` evaluates the initial number before starting to typeset the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `listings.sty` we find

```
\def\lst@InitLstNumber{%
     \global\c@lstnumber\lst@firstnumber
     \global\advance\c@lstnumber\lst@advancenumber
     \global\advance\c@lstnumber-\lst@advancelstnum
     \ifx \lst@firstnumber\c@lstnumber
         \global\advance\c@lstnumber-\lst@advancelstnum
     \fi%
     \lst@ifincluderangemarker\else%
         \global\advance\c@lstnumber by 1%
     \fi%
     }
```

and in `lstmisc.sty` there's other related code:

```
\lst@Key{firstnumber}{auto}{%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {auto&\let\lst@firstnumber\@undefined\\%
     last&\let\lst@firstnumber\c@lstnumber
    }{\def\lst@firstnumber{#1\relax}}}
\lst@AddToHook{PreSet}{\let\lst@advancenumber\z@}
\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}
    {\ifx\lst@firstnumber\@undefined
         \def\lst@firstnumber{\lst@lineno}%
     \fi}
\gdef\lst@SetFirstNumber{%
    \ifx\lst@firstnumber\@undefined
        \@tempcnta 0\csname\@lst no@\lst@intname\endcsname\relax
        \ifnum\@tempcnta=\z@ \@tempcnta\lst@firstline
                       \else \lst@nololtrue \fi
        \advance\@tempcnta\lst@advancenumber
        \edef\lst@firstnumber{\the\@tempcnta\relax}%
    \fi}
\gdef\lst@SaveFirstNumber{%
    \expandafter\xdef
        \csname\@lst no\ifx\lst@intname\@empty @ \else @\lst@intname\fi
        \endcsname{\the\c@lstnumber}}
\newcounter{lstnumber}% \global
\global\c@lstnumber\@ne % init
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\@arabic\c@lstnumber}
```

So, when `firstnumber=\inputlineno` is found when processing the options, the internal counter `lstnumber` is given the current value of `\inputlineno`, which always is the line number in the file being currently read by TeX, at the point of reading.

Thus the value of `\inputlineno` is asked for when

```
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=\inputlineno]
```

is being processed; for the actual typesetting of line numbers, `listings` uses the current value of `lstnumber`.

The workaround is, obviously,

```
firstnumber=\numexpr\inputlineno+1\relax
```

making sure the option is on the last line of the options, in case it is not used in a `\lstset`. So, for instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  numbers=left,
  frame = single,
  firstnumber=\numexpr\inputlineno+1\relax]
... here is some great code on line 6 in our file ...
\end{lstlisting}
This is line $\the\inputlineno$ in our file.
\end{document}
```

But the `\lstset` method is of course better.

[image]